# image upload failure from Gupshup chatbot through whatsapp channel

Tags: gupshup

I am using this

```
var image = {"type":"image","originalUrl":"image url here","previewUrl":"thumbnail url here"};
    context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(image));
```

format for uploading image to gupshup whatsapp chatbot, but image is not been send,
the error it is showing is

```
{
  "meta": {
    "api_status": "stable",
    "version": "2.21.4"
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 1014,
      "title": "Internal error",
      "details": "Image file format (application/octet-stream) is not supported"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the image URL you are trying to send to your users?

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for sending the image file as Content-Type `application/octet-stream` by WhatsApp hence you got the error.

Supported Content-Types are `image/jpeg`, `image/png`. Hence, you will have to provide Image URL which ends with image extension `.jpg/.jpeg/.png`

Comment: can you share the example which is working? I am not able to send image even after having correct url ending with .png extension.

Comment: It is possible for your to share the link of the image.